# Why am I receiving an error, saying that the Plugins.yml file doesn't exist when it does?

Tags: plugins

**Main.java**

```
package me.FactoryMC.FactoryBlocks;

import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.saveDefaultConfig();
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("fblock")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("factoryblocks.reload")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',
                        "&cYou require &6Dev &cor higher to use this command."));
                return true;
            }
            if (args.length == 0) {
                // - /fblock
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Use the correct format: /fblock reload");
                return true;
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                // - /fblock reload
                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("reload")) {
                    for (String msg : this.getConfig().getStringList("language.reload")) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', msg));
                    }
                    this.reloadConfig();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event) {
        this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("blocks").getKeys(false).forEach(key -> {
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(event.getBlock().getType().toString())) {
                ItemStack[] items = new ItemStack[this.getConfig().getStringList("blocks." + key).size()];
                ItemStack item = null;
                int position = 0;
                Random r = new Random();
                for (String i : this.getConfig().getStringList("blocks." + key)) {
                    try {
                        item = new ItemStack(Material.matchMaterial(i), r.nextInt(16));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        item = new ItemStack(Material.matchMaterial(key));
                    }
                    items[position] = item;
                    position++;
                }
                int num = r.nextInt(items.length);
                event.setDropItems(false);
                World world = event.getPlayer().getWorld();
                world.dropItemNaturally(event.getBlock().getLocation(), items[num]);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**plugin.yml**

```
main: me.FactoryMC.FactoryBlocks.Main
name: FactoryBlocks
author: FactoryMC
version: 1.0

commands:
  FactoryBlocks:
```

**Error Message:**

```
Could not load 'plugins\FactoryBlocks.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:160) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:144) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:383) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:185) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
```

**Screenshot (File Formatting)**
https://gyazo.com/0167c82d654139c4df62d78f10829879

If you haven't already noticed, I'm new to coding Minecraft Plugins - and I saw this as a good plugin to start off with. I've been trying to figure out how this is an error, but I couldn't figure it out.

Undoubtedly someone will be able to pick it up just by first glance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin.yml should not be inside your package! The plugin.yml (and config.yml) needs to be directly in the Java Project.